# how to create fixed length multi line text box

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

Need to limit character per line on multiline text box and also need to limit no of lines as well. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to implement your own control inherited from TextBox - then do your own validation in a TextChanged event handler.